# Asp.net Authorization using Azman and Store - xml, adam , sql ..etc

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml, authorization, azman

I am setting up Azman for authorization in my asp.net web application. I can have the Azman store as XML or ADAM or Sql server. 
My question is, which store (XML,ADAM,Sql,..etc) is better in what scenarios.

Please help.
Thanks/Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use XML for testing. I would also use it if I needed to distribute it as part of a small, lightweight app (maybe to disconnected laptops, etc.).

We use AD for small- to medium-sized apps where access control needs to be managed by a centralized administrative group, as long as the apps don't pound too heavily on the AD server. Also, for very high security apps, I would also need AD for auditing (non-repudiation defense in depth).

If we had apps that were very heavily used and had moderate or heavy AzMan dependencies, I would certainly store that in AD-LDS (aka ADAM).

I would probably consider SQL Server if I were making a world-wide distributed app that could take advantage of replication. I am not sure I get the value of using SQL Server very much.